# ResourcesCDVNotification.bundle: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

Hello please solve my problem,

```
(null): error: /Users/72001432/Desktop/yoobi/ios/Smallapp/Resources/ResourcesCDVNotification.bundle: No such file or directory



error: /Users/72001432/Desktop/yoobi/ios/Smallapp/Resources/ResourcesCDVCapture.bundle: No such file or directory
```

when i build then i will get this error. i am using xcode 6.3 with target ios 6 . help me to fix this please

Comment: Hi, do you resolve your error ? i have exactlly the same error :(

Comment: Yes @tamtoum1987 long back

Comment: Do you remember how do you resolve this problem ?

Comment: its hybrid  app right. open with Xcode goto Project target -->Link Binnary with Lib , (+)Add CDVNotification.boundle if shows. Or else Download CDVNotification boundle Manual and add on your project

Comment: But the problem is ResourcesCDVNotification not CDVNotification 

i can't find ResourcesCDVNotification.bundle to download it